# Object Detection from image with training data using auto learning algorithm

Tags: c#, image, opencv, image-processing, object-detection

I am trying to make an application which will do 2 task.

1. get some object from an image e.g a rectangle which actually a
   traffic light.
2. Find this selected object in training data,training data is actually
   bulk of images.

I have searched found an `OpenCV` library which can be use but how can i start it.How can i detect some specific shape from image and find it in training data with matching probability.

Also is there any algorithm which is auto learning..?

Answer (score 0):

You would need to have stored the coordinates of the rectangle in a CSV file(for example) along with the path to the image. You would then load the image along with the coordinates to get the traffic light as a subimage. This, I think, answers question 1.

You would then feed these subimages, which would be your positive dataset along with some negative data, which could be random portions of the image that don't overlap with the traffic light, into a machine learning algorithm like a HOG SVM. There are some nice tutorials in Python here: http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2014/11/10/histogram-oriented-gradients-object-detection/
This, I think, would lead you to solving question 2.

Does that answer your question? Or have I misinterpreted it?